# How should I search a group of files using linux `find` command?

Tags: bash

I have a group of files in a certain directory. Now I want to search them in two different directories. I used below code:

```
(jumped to the directory that contains that group of files)
ls | while read name; do find ~/dir1 ~/dir2 -name {$name};done
```

But I guess it is too slow since for each file, `dir1` and `dir2` should be searched once. So the search will be do too many times.

Is my guess right? and if so, what should I write?

Comment: Once I did something like this, my solution was to generate the `find` argument list, and call it only once. In your case, I would do `ls | while read name; do l_name="${l_name} -name ${name}"; done; find dir1 dir2 ${l_name}`

Comment: @AlfredE.Noobman The question is not to look for `string` in files, but to find location of files named `name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/FIND/) supports `-o` for OR operation.

You can use this:

```
files=(); # Initialize an empty bash array
for i in *; do files+=(-o -name "$i"); done # Add names of all the files to the array
find dir1/ dir2/ -type f '(' "${files[@]:1}" ')' # Search for those files
```

e.g., consider this case:

```
$ touch a b c
$ ls
a b c
$ files=()
$ for i in *; do files+=(-o -name "$i"); done
$ printf '%s ' "${files[@]}"; echo
-o -name a -o -name b -o -name c 
$ printf '%s ' "${files[@]:1}"; echo
-name a -o -name b -o -name c 
$ printf '%s ' find dir1/ dir2/ -type f '(' "${files[@]:1}" ')'; echo
find dir1/ dir2/ -type f ( -name a -o -name b -o -name c )  # This is the command that actually runs.
```

Comment: I know `$` refers to a variable in bash shell. Can you please explain the usage of `@` and `:1` in more details?